# Is there a way to test if a pct change, reduction, or growth, from one time point to another for one group is statistically significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

For example:

County A, of it's 3000 residents, 500 were vaccinated against the flu

After intervention, County A's flu vaccination rate was 2000 of its 3000 residents.

I know we can get a percent change from this, but considering this is a n = 1, is there even a way to see if this difference is statistically significant using any of the known statistical tests.

In effect, I believe this is called a one group, pre-test post-test design.

TIA

Comment: What question would statistical significance answer?

Comment: The second number of 2000, does this also include the 500 from before the intervention? Is there any other factor which might have influenced the rate before/after? For ex. was  there was a shortage of vaccines before intervention, which could be the main cause rather than the intervention?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in whether the vaccination proportion is different between two samples, then a 2 sample proportion test could answer this (code in R)

```
> prop.test(c(500,2000),c(3000,3000))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(500, 2000) out of c(3000, 3000)
X-squared = 1540.8, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5218368 -0.4781632
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.1666667 0.6666667
```

although you really didn't need a test for this, the difference is obvious.

Note: this test assumes independent samples, if the samples are dependent (or paired) then a McNemar's test could be used instead.

Comment: No, this test cannot answer the question directly: the 500 people are included in the 2000, making these results strongly dependent, whereas your test assumes independence.